# BIT(1) or TINYINT for flags in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I often have tables where I need to store a flag which can either be 1 or 0 (true or false, etc).

I've previously used TINYINT.

Should I instead use BIT(1)?  Why or why not?

Comment: You should use `Bit` because it can only be the two values you care about.  Thus, `TinyInt` is wasted space.

Comment: What version of mysql? Per the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html), *Before 5.0.3, BIT is a synonym for TINYINT(1).*

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.37, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: The BIT(1) is slightly more efficient.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  But I thought you said it was synonyms for `TINYINT(1)`.  Why would it be more efficient?

Comment: @user1032531 Last time I checked 5.5.37 is after 5.0.3 - the documentation further says *This data type was added in MySQL 5.0.3 for MyISAM, and extended in 5.0.5 to MEMORY, InnoDB, BDB, and NDBCLUSTER. Before 5.0.3, BIT is a synonym for TINYINT(1).*

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  Maybe I should practice reading!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you use a mysql version greater then 5.0.3 `Bit` isn't anymore an alias for `Tinyint` but if you create a `bit` column it gets anyway `1 Byte`.

so use `Bit(1)` or `Tinyint(1)` is equal and you get no benefits if your table had only 1 `Bit` column.

but if you had more true/false columns i suggest you to use `Bit` as each value of the bit columns are placed in the same `1 Byte` until it is filled.

if u use mysql lower then 5.0.3 then use `tinyint` or `bit` is totally fine. if you look at the mysql documentation on `bool` types you see that it is a alias for `tinyint`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html

> BOOL, BOOLEAN
>
> These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered
>   false. Nonzero values are considered true:

---

> BIT is a synonym for TINYINT(1).

Comment: Currently, I am using `TINYINT` which I believe defaults to `TINYINT(256)`.  Guess it is easy enough to change to `TINYINT(1)`.  Exactly the same as `BIT(1)`?

Comment: @ins0 you beat me this time...+1

Comment: Per the referenced documentation, Before 5.0.3, BIT is a synonym for TINYINT(1).   What if I have a later version of MySQL (5.5.37 for instance)?

Comment: If you ever need to use a join on the table, don't use bit. You can run into bugs. I'm using mysql version 5.6, and when joining two tables with the same names for the bit column, the results become unpredictable. Even when you output  the same column twice with a single query with a join, you can get a different value each time.

Comment: hate to break it to everyone, but, `tinyint(1)` will store between -128 and +127. the 1 is nothing more than display width.

Comment: if you use `tinyint(1) unsigned` the range is 0 to 255