# MySql - Which column type to use for storing multiple booleans in multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, boolean, multiple-columns

I would like to save multiple booleans in a table. I want to use multiple columns rather than one Bit(N) column. Now I'm thinking about whether I should use Bool = tinyint(1) or bit(1) columns.
I read this older [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25428904/10994214) from a similar question and want to know if

> but if you had more true/false columns i suggest you to use Bit as each value of the bit columns are placed in the same 1 Byte until it is filled.

is true. Can anybody confirm this? Which column type should I use in the year 2020 for this case?

Thanks,
Regards

Comment: Are you asking because you're concerned about how much space they'll use?

Comment: Not that concerned. I just would like to have a reason to use bit rather than bool or vice versa. I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Are you sure that each but should be a separate column, rather than a separate row?

Comment: Would like to save, lets say user status and type and concat and conv it to get bitflags.

Comment: If youre using hibernate/JPA boolean usually will be an int(1), i think they know better

Answer (score 2):

The native `BOOLEAN` type is intended to be used to store booleans. Yes, apparently `BOOLEAN` takes up a byte instead of a bit (it may not actually be the case that `BIT(1)` only uses one bit of space; see notes below). But it's not going to make a noticeable difference in how much space your database takes up. Consider this, if you have 10 booleans in a table and you end up with a million records, that's just 10MB of space taken up by the booleans vs 1.25MB taken up if you used a bit. Even if you get to 100 million records, that's only 1GB of space. If you have 100 million records, you'll have enough space that 1GB won't matter.

Here are some notes on `BOOLEAN`, `TINYINT` and `BIT` that might help clarify why you'd want to go with `BOOLEAN`:

1. `BOOLEAN` is intended to be used to store boolean values. You can trust the implementation details to the Mysql developers.
2. `BOOLEAN` carries semantic meaning; it clearly indicates the intended purpose of the column is to store a boolean.
3. It turns out that `BIT(1)` actually takes up 1 byte as well. From [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html):

> BIT(M) requires approximately (M+7)/8 bytes

So `BIT(1)` would require `(1+7)/8 bytes` or `1 byte`.

4. You may read that, since `BOOLEAN` is synonymous with `TINYINT`, you can store values other than `TRUE` and `FALSE` in a `BOOLEAN` (e.g. you might be able to store a `22`). However, if you try to insert e.g. `22` into a `BOOLEAN` column, Mysql will interpret it as `TRUE` (and it will interpret a `0` as `FALSE`). So, you don't need to worry about weird values getting into your `BOOLEAN` column. See this [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fd274/1) for an example.

Comment: This answers the opposite question

Comment: @Strawberry How so?

Comment: Which data type should the op use? If the criterion isn't memory, then what is it?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use VARCHAR data type to store the bit(N) and it will take space with what you store in the first place, example "0101000" which means you have 7 boolean. The 2nd and 4th would be TRUE and other would be FALSE that would use 7+1 bytes in your storage (CMIIW)

cheers :)

Comment: Why would you use `VARCHAR` instead of `BIT` for storing a bit value?

Comment: 'storagewise' if you need only 8 columns of boolean better use bit yes it would only use 1 byte (CMIIW).
if you only need TRUE/FALSE i might prefer using tinyint(1)  or char(1)

well i guess just to 'outmaneuver' database vs coding (which is better or just preferences)